# Запароленные ячейки эксель-файла

Tags: excel

Имеется эксель-файл, в котором проводятся расчеты, ячейки, куда выводятся результаты расчетов запаролены. Можно ли как-то посмотреть, по каким формулам ведутся расчеты, не зная пароля?

Answer (score 1):

Не зная пароля, посмотреть формулы нельзя. Умеючи - можно. Защита у офисных программ слабая.
Но если стоит защита, значит, кому-то это нужно? Кто-то пытался не допустить туда шаловливые ручки да глазки?

Comment: да нет, это не с целью обмана или чего-то такого, а просто программу надо написать, выполняющую аналогичные расчеты, а формулы запаролены.

Comment: Свяжитесь со мной, попробую помочь:
viktturСОБАКАru
(адрес размещен по согласованию с администрацией форума).

Но помощь по задаче, не по взлому защиты.